# Recover lost changes during unfinished rebasing

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I lost a lot of my work because I had unfinished rebase. I find out it when I was trying commit my 2 day work. I couldn't commit works until rebase is not resolved, so I abort it, because skip or continue didn't work. But with abort all my changes are gone ... can you tell me if it possible to recover these data please? Thank you in advice.

Comment: For the future: have a look at git stash.

Comment: @Christoph I know ... I hate myself for that but it is late :/

Comment: Once a version of code is committed, git is tenacious about hanging on to it; but until it's committed, git has no real means to preserve the information.  Generally it will try to avoid clobbering the work tree for this reason, but in this circumstance it interpreted your changes as unwanted attempts to resolve a rebase conflict (or something along those lines) so, when instructed to abort the rebase, was willing to throw them out.  The only hope would be if you have a backup of the work tree (from outside git)

Comment: @Mark isn't there something like "rebase log file" which could help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850167/5784831

Comment: Anything you `git add`ed within the last few weeks is still in the repository whether or not you committed it, hunt up `git fsck --no-reflogs --lost-found`.  Commits cement the content into history, but `git add` is what puts it in the repository in the first place.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are using Intellij Idea you can use Idea's Local History.

Right click on package of source code which you want to restore (e.g, main) and select `Local History > Show History` and you will see your code history (also uncommited changes). Now you can find change when you lost your code and revert it.

[image]

Comment: That's just wow! I had some interns recently doing work in pycharm and not committing the code and losing work. This will be a lifesaver for them :-)

Comment: This is golden, I rolled back an unstaged file and thought I lost it forever - never knew there's a history on a package. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ itself is extremely aggressive about indexing and versioning your local changes to files (for me, it goes back months).  Even if git has no way of helping, you might be able to recover your changes from IntelliJ.

Try this:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click on the root folder for your project and click Local History > Show History
2. From the list of changes on the left, find the revision that you want to restore.  IntelliJ labels revisions with additional helpful information like tests passing, commits, etc.
3. Right-click on the revision and click Revert to restore the directory to that revision.  Alternatively, use Create Patch to create a patch file.

Answer (score 1):

Check shelf first.
I Experienced `All files changed during 'Apply Patch' action were rolled back` after aborting. It turns out my changes were automatically shelved by the ide (particularly when I checked out at some point I think) so all I had to do was unshelf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git reflog`? If you can remember what you put in your last valid commit, you can repoint your HEAD to the right one. Check out [this article](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) if you want to understand more about it.

Comment: The op is asking about uncommitted changes. Sadly reflow doesn’t solve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a `git rebase` command with unstaged/uncommitted work and for whatever reason the operation fails and you lose your work, check your project's `.git` directory for any folders with the word `*rebase*` in the folder name. If you find a file named `autostash` in any of these directories, run the command `git stash apply <COMMIT_HASH>` using the hash contained in the `autostash` file; hopefully it will contain the lost files. You can also create a new branch with the stash if you prefer using `git branch <NEW_BRANCH_NAME> <COMMIT_HASH>`. This will for whatever reason list the stash changes as a commit, and I do not know what unwanted side-effects this may cause, but it can help you recover work.

It seems like this stash is hidden so running `git stash list` will not return the autostash. I believe git automatically creates an autostash when you have the configuration `rebase.autostash true` set.

I have a developer I was able to rescue thanks to this. The dev in question was working on changes and had not staged/committed any of his work; he ran a `pull` operation from Visual Studios, it hung, so he closed Visual Studios which left his repo with an incomplete rebase. I could not find the autostash in any of the `reflogs` or `stashes`, but the stash hash was saved to the `autostash` file. We applied the stash and he got all his uncommitted work back; work stemming back 1 month.